# Using Autofac to find plugins

Tags: c#, autofac

Having a heck of a time figuring out how to get Autofac to load plugins. I'm new to Autofac.

I have plugins like ServiceA.dll, ServiceB.dll, etc. When configuring my Autofac container I scan the current directory for Service*.dll and pull the name of the service "A", "B", out of the filename and store in a variable named serviceName. Then I find the type of the service class that implements IService and put it in a variable named serviceType. Each service also has a config setting class named <serviceName>Settings so I find that class and put its type in a variable named serviceSettingsType. Then register:

```
builder.RegisterType(serviceType)
  .Named<IService>(serviceName);
builder.RegisterType(serviceSettingsType)
  .Named<IServiceSettings>(serviceName+"Settings")
```

After building the Autofac config, I can get a service type like so:

```
scope.ResolveNamed<IService>("A");
```

And presto, the class ServiceA is instantiated. However, ServiceA takes a ctor param:

```
public class ServiceA(ServiceASettings settings) {}
```

Autofac instantiates a ServiceASettings class just fine (it's just a "data class" with one or more properties) and passes that into the ctor of ServiceA.

What I can't figure out is how to tell Autofac that to create a ServiceASettings class to pass into the ServiceA ctor it needs to instantiate a SettingsManager class and then call `var settings = await Task<T> ReadFromFile(string settingsFilename)` (where T is the type of the ASettings class) and use that settings class in ServiceA's ctor call. Just like the service name above ("A" in the example) is determined from the command line, the settingsFilename passed to the ReadFromFileAsync needs to be passed in at runtime.

Hope this makes sense. I feel like I'm very close to loading plugins with Autofac but just can't figure out the proper factory calls or named parameter calls for the Service ctor. Anyone done something similar to this with Autofac? Suggestions for changing the architecture of my plugin classes and/or SettingsManager class are also more than welcome if it helps make this work easier with Autofac.

EDIT:

Got this to work. I re-read the page @cynic pointed to and the syntax runtime parameters finally clicked for me.

Changed my SettingsManager class to one called SettingsFile that takes a Type, an IFileSystem, and a string with the filename and exposes a ReadSettings method. Register:

```
builder.Register((c, p) => new SettingsFile(
    c.Resolve<IFileSystem>(),
    p.Named<Type>("settingsType"),
    p.Named<string>("settingsFilename")))
    .As<ISettingsFile>();
```

Resolve:

```
var settingsName = "Service1Settigns";
var settingsType = scope.ResolveNamed<ISettings>(settingsName);
var settingsFile = scope.Resolve<ISettingsFile>(
    new NamedParameter("settingsType", settingsType.GetType()),
    new NamedParameter("settingsFilename", settingsFilename));
var settings = settingsFile.ReadSettings();
```

(I think there's a way to get the resolver to call ReadSettings for me, but haven't figured that out yet. But I'll probably want to trap errors and enhance with very specific error messages anyhow.)

Then while scanning the plugin DLLs the various classes are registered like so:

```
var assemblyTypes = assembly.GetTypes();
var settingsTypes = FindType(assemblyTypes, typeof(ISettings));
var settingsType = settingsTypes.First();
builder.RegisterType(settingsType).Named<ISettings>(settingsName);
```

Similar registering is done for IService and IRepository and here's how a client is fired up:

```
var client = scope.ResolveNamed<IClient>(clientName,
    new NamedParameter("settings", settings),
    new NamedParameter("repository", repository));
```

This gives me an IClient based on the clientName which in this case is specified on the command line (as is the appropriate settings file path to use for this client).

Getting to really like the features of Autofac!

Comment: From briefly skimming the documentation, I guess you want the `ResolvedParameter` for your "service" registration, telling it to use the corresponding "service configuration" - see http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html

Comment: What did you try ?